# Angular 2 i18n: translating <option> values

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I'm moving my application from ng2-translate into native i18n support. Facing a problem when it comes to translate a  with a few options:

```
<md-select placeholder="Salutation" i18n-placeholder>
        <md-option *ngFor="let s of salutations" [value]="s.value">{{s.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html) doesn't specify how to obtain the option values into my XLF file when they are served via TS. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answer** I guess was a mistake in the config. All works now with
`<target>{testRandom, plural,  =0 {none} =1 {single} other {several}}</target>`

Comment: I don't understand anything from your answer.